# How to parse an <img> that is deep within a div using Element Parser?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, c, parsing

I'm currently using an parser called [Element Parser](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/) and I'm trying to parse an img tag that is the 4th img tag down under the div id "Group-E". I can retrieve the 2nd img but not anything after the 2nd img. The img that I'm wanting to parse is:

```
<img src="http://example.com/I_need_this_image_here.jpg" />.
```

How can this be done? So far I've used the following code to get the 1st img tag:

```
Element* needIMG = [document selectElement: @"div.edgeTop div#Group-E img"];
```

HTML Code trying to parse

```
<div class="edgeTop">
<div id="Group-E">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" id="image" />        <img src="http://example.com/image2.png" border="5" />

    <h4>Group - Section E</h4>

    <div class="efs" style="width:28px;">Group:</div>E<br />
    <div class="efs" style="width:28px;">Link:</div><a href="Group/E">Group E</a><br />
    <div class="efs" style="width:28px;">Date:</div><strong>Febuary 15, 2001</strong> by <strong><a href="http://example.com/date">Date</a></strong><br />
    <br />

    <img src="http://example.com/image3.gif" class="image" style="padding: 0 4px 7px 0;" />Group;.  <b>Group E</b><br /><br />Group E Other: 
    <img src="http://example.com/I_need_this_image_here.jpg" />  Other:<br /><a href="http://www.example.com/other" target="_blank" class="url">Group Site</a>
    <div class="efs">
        <div style="padding:18px 0 1px 8px;">Link Pics:</div>
        <img src="http://example.com/linkpic.gif" class="imagelink"/> </div>
</div>
<div class="efsl"></div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after hours of trial and error. You have to use the "+" selector to get the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a class to the image you want to parse such as...

```
<img class="imgtoparse" src="http://example.com/I_need_this_image_here.jpg" />
```